Why does a small shape parameter in the skew normal distribution invert the skewness?
I am using the rsnorm function from the fGarch R library. As one would expect, for shape parameter (xi in this implementation) that is sufficiently large (abs(xi) > 1), a histogram has a clearly visible skewness. However, for -1 < xi < 1, the skewness appears to be in the wrong direction. For example, consider the following:
library('fGarch')
n <- 10000
xis <- c( -5, -2, -1, -0.1, 0.1, 1, 2, 5 )
for (xi in xis) {
   r <- rsnorm(n,xi=xi)
   title <- as.character(xi)
   hist(r, main=title)
}

Am I misinterpreting xi? It seems that for abs(xi) == 1 there is symmetry. If that is the case, how does the method of moment estimate for xi work for small skewness parameter (see the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution where the shape parameter is alpha rather than xi (wikipedia has xi as the location parameter)?
Many thanks for any insights.

You might want to try a different R package that has skew normal distribution functions.  The documentation for dsnorm in fGarch doesn't given the definition of the density used so that's another reason to try a different package.  Not to mention that one gets negative density values when xi < 0.

Many thanks for the suggestion to use a different library. If I use library sn instead, the results are as expected:
library('sn')
library('moments')
n <- 10000
alphas <- c( -5, -2, -1, -0.1, 0.1, 1, 2, 5 )
for (alpha in alphas) {
   r <- rsn(n,alpha=alpha)
   title <- as.character(alpha)
   hist(r, main=title)
   cat(alpha, skewness(r))
}

